# JavaScript ID tag selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a better way to write `jQuery('#'+ myId)` in JavaScript.
I have an ID in a variable without the `#` character and `jQuery('#'+ myId)` looks ugly.

```
var myId = 'last-element-id';
jQuery('#'+ myId)
```

I'd like to avoid the `+` character to join the strings.
Thanks

Comment: please show some more code, as we have discussion that we are trying to guess - what you want to do with `myId`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But, have in mind that returned element is not a jQuery collection

```
function getElement(element) {
    return document.getElementById(element)
}
```

Comment: You could wrap the returned object by jQuery: `$(document.get...)`

Comment: You can do antything what you need. Author of the qustion did not mention for what he / she needs it.

Comment: He/she wants to create a _jQuery object_ so wrapping the returned value with jQuery makes sense. Also, when the query fails jQuery handles it without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
function jQueryID(myId){
    return jQuery('#'+ myId);
}
```

and then call like

```
jQueryId(myId);
```

Answer (score 0):

As simple as that:

```
var myId = '#last-element-id';
jQuery(myId);
```

or

```
var myId = '#' + 'last-element-id'; // if 'last-element-id' is dynamically generated value
jQuery(myId);
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is so obvious... I'm looking for a method, if it does exist.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you are using jQuery, is better you stick with jQuery in all your code.
My offer is, create a function as below:

```
var getId = function(id){
    return '#'+ id;
}
```

and call that anywhere you need, and stick with jQuery. like this:

```
$(getId(id));
```